# How to implement newest Material icons in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, icons, material-design

At this time, an application made with Flutter and Material 3 does not use the newest icons from https://fonts.google.com/icons

New:[image: Home icon Material 3] Currently:[image]

There is also missing icons

New: [image] Currently: (Not implemented)

Flutter icons seems to be [Material 2 icons](https://m2.material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#design-principles) instead of [Material 3 icons](https://m3.material.io/styles/icons/overview)

Is there a way to update icons or use a package that includes the new ones ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this pub [material_symbols_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons).

As far as I know there is no proper way to use Material Symbols before Google adds the support directly into Flutter, so, for now, I would go for this pub.

Happy coding!